# Retrieve only modified rows in DataTables

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I render a page with two columns where one has input fields and the other one checkboxes.
Lets say I modify an entry in one of the input fields and I uncheck a checkbox in another row.

Right now when I click the Save button and call the below code I receive all onscreen rows without it's properties modified with the new values (ie. I'm getting the original values and states from when the table originally loaded).

```
save: function() {
    var self = this;
    var data = JSON.stringify(this.dataTable.rowData());
    var url = this.urls.saveScreen;
    var ajaxOptions = { url: url, data: data, contentType: "application/json", type: "POST"};
}
```

Is there different call available then "this.dataTable.rowData()" that I could use to receive:

a.) only modified rows

b.) rows with included changes to the input fields made by the user after the table was loaded.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden fields for that.. Add a hidden Field with the element changed in the  table..

```
$('table > *').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().append('<input type="hidden">changed</input>');
});
```

Now while checking you can search for rows having hidden input fields having value "changed"

Assuming it to be a table:

```
$('input:hidden :contains("changed"').each(function(){
    var row=$(this).closest('tr');
    var firstElement=row.find('td:eq("0")').text();
    var secondElement=row.find('td:eq("1")').text();
    // and so on
});
```

This code is untested, But It should give you a workaround on how things should work..

Comment: Well, but I'm using the DataTables (table plug-in for jQuery) to render my table. Do you have any idea if there's a build in logic in that jquery extension that allows me to retrieve the modified rows?

Comment: I have No idea about how datatables treat modified rows.. But the above code should work fine..